# Two forms in function def post

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I have a written function `def post` which works for the form of adding comments to posts. In this case, when I send a rate form, no records are added to the database. I need to edit this function so that when I sending a form with a rated post, all data in the form will be saved in the database, as it should. In database by form I need save the value of the rating, user who rated, date and the post which was rated.

Just I need after sending form it adds values to the database.

**views.py**:

```
class IndexView(AllAdsViewMixin, ListView):
    model = UserContent
    template_name = 'user_content/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'object'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last all five published contents"""
        return UserContent.objects.filter(state='1').order_by('-published')[:5]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        comment_initial_data = {
            'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model).id
        }

        reply_initial_data = {
            'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Comment).id
        }

        comment_form = CommentForm(initial=comment_initial_data)
        reply_form = CommentForm(initial=reply_initial_data)
        mainpage_images = MainPageImages.objects.first()
        rate_form = RateForm()
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = comment_form
        context['reply_form'] = reply_form
        context['mainpage_images'] = mainpage_images
        context['rate_form'] = rate_form

        return context

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content_type_id = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
            object_id_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
            content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')

            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(content_type_id)
            print(object_id_data)
            print(content_data)

            new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                user=request.user,
                content_type=content_type,
                object_id=object_id_data,
                content=content_data,
            )

        else:
            print(comment_form.errors)

        return self.get(request, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Rate


class RateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rate
        fields = (
          'rate_value',
        )
```

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from user_content.models import UserContent


class Rate(models.Model):
    user_content = models.ForeignKey(UserContent,
                                     related_name='rates',
                                     verbose_name=_('User Content')
                                     )
    rate_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=3,
                                     verbose_name=_('rates'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             verbose_name=_('User')
                             )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Created'), auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: We need to see the form to give you an answer.

Comment: Added models.py and forms.py. Sorry, my bad.